# Проблема с CK Editor

Tags: php, ckeditor

Прикрутил к сайту ck editor.Написал скрипт админки, где можно добавлять и редактировать статьи.При добавлении статьи все нормально, а при редактировании возвращает из базы в текстовое поле редактора только часть текста.
Не пойму, в чем проблема, в Editor или в php.Вот код

```
<div class="editor">
<?php 
  $material = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `id`=".(int) $_GET['id']);
  $mat = mysqli_fetch_array($material);
 ?>
    <form action="post_update.php" name="postform" method="post" onsubmit="return validate_form ( );">
        <label for="">Введите заголовок статьи</label><br>
        <input type="text" name=title value="<?php echo $mat['title']; ?>"><br>
        <label for="">Выберите категорию</label><br>
        <select name="category">
            <?php 
            $label = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `categories`");
            while($lab = mysqli_fetch_assoc($label)){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $lab['id']; ?>"><?php echo $lab['title']; ?></option>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </select><br>
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $mat['id']; ?>">
        <label for="">Введите текст</label><br>
        <textarea id="text" name="text"><?php echo $mat['text']; ?></textarea><br>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            CKEDITOR.replace( 'text');
        </script>
        <input type="submit" name="edit_post" value="Сохранить">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: в базе то целиком записано? не обрезается текст?

Comment: Да, целиком записывается.И на сайте целиком выводится

Comment: Блин, посмотрел, я же там код писал без всякого форматирования.Прямо с клавиатуры.Может из-за этого?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно у вас прокрутка в окне редактора отключена так как сам редактор текст не режет.
И еще попробуйте добавить в textarea параметры rows и cols

```
<textarea id='text' name='text' rows=15 cols=85>
```

Comment: Спасибо, они изначально мною добавлены.Проблема в том была,что в статье код Jquery описывается.Обычный текст выводится полностью.Буду пробовать <pre>.Только другая проблема нарисовалась: если в заголовке есть кавычки, то обрезает все, что после первой кавычки.Это уже PHP виноват.Поле заголовка VARCHAR, 255